# WebMvcTest requires mocking beans defined in SpringBootApplication class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-test

I am using @WebMvcTest to test a controller. I have observed that I need to mock the autowired bean in the SpringBoot application class in the test class. As per my understanding, with @WebMvcTest I can test the controller independently. Just wondering why I need to mock EmployeeService used in SpringBootApplication class. Below are the relevant classes -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EmployeeController.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

   @Autowired
   MockMvc mockMvc;

   @MockBean
   EmployeeService employeeService;

   @Test
   public void getEmployee() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/employee")
                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                   .andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
  }
```

SpringBootApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

   @Autowired
   EmployeeService employeeService;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }
 }
```

EmployeeController

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

   @GetMapping(value = "/employee")
   public Employee getEmployee() {
      return Employee.builder().
            name("Harry")
            .id("1")
            .build();
   }
 }
```

Employee bean

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {    
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I am using SpringBoot version 2.1.6

Comment: because you need `EmployeeService ` bean in application context

Comment: @Deadpool, I thought the goal of WebMvcTest was to test the controller standalone. There should not any need to inject mocks for beans used in Application context right?